# Async & Await issue in a Metro Style app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have a simple Metro style app that's giving me an issue with (async & await).

```
List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
...
...
LoadList();
...
...
(Problem) Code that accesses the elements of the fileNames List
...
...

private async void LoadList()
{
    // Code that loops through a directory and adds the 
    // file names to the fileNames List using GetFilesAsync()
}
```

The problem is that the fileNames List is accessed prematurely - before it is fully loaded with items. 
This is because of the async method - the program continues with the next line of code while the async method continues its processing.

How can I access the List after it is fully loaded (After the async method is done)?

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do without using async in Metro apps ?

Comment: This appears to be the wrong place to be using async.  You actually WANT this to be a synchronous operation.

Comment: @Dan-o I am using GetFoldersAsync() and GetFilesAsync(). Are there synchronous alternatives for these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the calling method to be asynchronous too - and rather than having a variable of `fileNames`, I'd make the `LoadList` method return it. So you'd have:

```
public async Task ProcessFiles()
{
    List<string> fileNames = await LoadList();
    // Now process the files
}

public async Task<List<string>> LoadList()
{
    List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
    // Do stuff...
    return fileNames;
}
```

This does mean that you need to wait for all the files to be found before you start processing them; if you want to process them *as you find them* you'll need to think about using a `BlockingCollection` of some kind. EDIT: As Stephen points out, [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg585582.aspx) would be a great fit here too.

Comment: +1. Though instead of `BlockingCollection`, I would recommend [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg585582.aspx).

Comment: @StephenCleary: Good point; will put that in. (I should really read up on Dataflow again. I did a while ago, but it clearly didn't sink in...)

Comment: @JonSkeet and StephenCleary - Thank you for your replies.
It appears I need to do this in a synchronous manner. Right now I'm using GetFoldersAsync() and GetFilesAsync() from the StorageFolder class. What 'synchronous' alternative can I use instead of these two methods?

Comment: @nv.snow: *Why* do you need to do this in a synchronous manner?

Comment: @JonSkeet - Mainly because the rest of the program depends on this List and If I jump to the next line of code before the List is fully loaded, it breaks. Plus, I don't have hundreds of files that I need to access so I don't think a synchronous alternative will have a huge impact. I tried the Async methods because that's what I found when I looked for ways to access files and directories.

Comment: @nv.snow: Well, if you've got access to `Task.Result` in your app, then that will block... but really, the whole of WinRT is aimed at being as asynchronous as possible. Trying to be synchronous is basically bucking the system.